# How to grep and treat meta character as normal character?

Tags: shell, grep, quoting

I am trying to recursively find some pattern which contains meta character.

Pattern that I searching for is `template <int N>`

I have tried :

```
grep -F -lir "template <int N>"  *    # trying to find "template <int>"
                                      # -F treat meta char as normal char
```

I get:

```
     grep: \<int: No such file or directory   
     grep: N\>: No such file or directory
     ..
     ...
```

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly the command you gave? The way you present it, with the quotes, works for me.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes .. I am using OSX

Comment: So that's the reason. Mate, things are a bit a bit different on OS X. I think you need to read this [article](http://ss64.com/osx/grep_pattern.html). I hope it helps.

Comment: What shell are you running this in? It work for me on OS X in bash, ksh, tcsh and csh.

Comment: @Kusalananda When I do echo $0 I get -bash

Comment: And what `grep`?  `grep --version` on my OS X (El Capitan 10.11.5) returns "grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD".

Comment: @Kusalananda So the problem was really stupid : I was searching for "template <int N>" but the file had "template<int N>"

Comment: Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Still shouldn't give you that error message though... Did you actually run it with the quotes as you typed it in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42925/discussion-between-pokche-and-kusalananda).

Comment: I wondered about that error. To get it, I had to double-quote the redirections as separate words (`"\<"`) OR pass the pattern (quoted) through a variable: `pat="template \<int N\>"; grep -Fi $pat test.input`. This runs into word-splitting: i.e. the shell splits the variable on the spaces, since it's expanded outside quotes, so grep gets multiple arguments and treats the latter ones as file names. (This was on OS X, but it works the same on Linux)

Comment: @ilkkachu I get the error in both cases (single quote and double quote) though

Comment: @Kusalananda So I had posted the problem in grep bug report and turns out it not a bug and was my fault. I had edited my .profile file  to make sure grep defaults to --color=auto by  doing /usr/bin/grep --color=auto $* and this was the problem. I should have done  /usr/bin/grep --color=auto "$@"  after this the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `fgrep` (or the `-F` option to `grep` that does the same), and write your query without escaping the `"<"` and `">"`.  I'd also suggest using single-quotes `'` rather than double-quotes `"`, since the shell may expand what it think is variables and such when you use double-quotes.

`fgrep -i 'template <int N>' *`

Comment: @Baard Kopperud : When I do fgrep -lirE 'template <int N>' * --exclude-dir={dir1}  : It cannot find the file. I do have a file with that pattern but that file does not show up

Comment: `fgrep -E` feels a bit redundant. GNU grep even complains about it.

Comment: @don, exactly. I'm off to sleep.

Comment: apparently When I use grep -F problem happen but when I use fgrep the problem vanishes